# IOS 5 TWTweetComposeViewController duplicate tweet

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, duplicates

I'm using twitter sharing via TWTweetComposeViewController in my app. When i tried to send tweets with same content, i'm getting an error says "The tweet, ... is a duplicate and cannot be sent". This case only happens when i try to send tweets with same content i've sent before.

The code i used is :

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
        {
            TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
            [tweetSheet setInitialText:messageText];
            [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
        }
```

Is anybody here saw this case before?

Comment: if you send duplicate tweet it give you error code 203.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter doesn't allow you to send the same tweet in a short time interval. It's impossible to do this.

You must wait some time before sending the exact same tweet again.